# How to insert a vector into another vector in a specific place so that i will get a big vector of both and that place will be overwritten?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2019, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

for an exercise i really need to know how to insert one vector into another.

here is an example of what i need:

```
//let's say i have these 2 vecs: 
vec1 = { 18, 192, 34};
vec2 = { 171, 11, 50, 6};
```

and i choose the point where to connect them, lets say i choose vec 1 to be
in place 2 of vector 2 like so:

```
result_vec = { 171, vec1, 50, 6};
```

so what i will actually get when i'm done is:

```
result_vec = { 171, 18, 192, 34, 50, 6};
```

for me it will be even better to see two examples, a simple example and another example with smart pointers like shared_ptr or unique_ptr.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think shared_prt and unique_ptr are relevant to your question and the tags could be removed. If you have problems with code that does use smart pointers you should show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to substitute one element of one vector for elements of another vector. If so then you can write a function similar to that shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> & replace( std::vector<T> &v1, 
                          typename std::vector<T>::size_type pos,
                          const std::vector<T> &v2 )
{
    if ( not ( pos < v1.size() ) )
    {
        v1.insert( std::end( v1 ), std::begin( v2 ), std::end( v2 ) );
    }
    else
    {
        v1.insert( v1.erase( std::next( v1.begin(), pos ) ),
                   std::begin( v2 ), std::end( v2 ) );
    }

    return v1;
}                          

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 171, 11, 50, 6 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 18, 192, 34 };

    for ( const auto &item : replace( v1, 1, v2 ) ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
171 18 192 34 50 6
```

Comment: seems like I misread the question, +1 for being more attentive than me ;)

Comment: Thanks for both of you!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it helps to browse some reference and look at the methods the container offers. Most of the time you will find that there is a method that does what you want out of the box. In this case it is [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) (overload (4)). To remove the old element at that place you can use [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec1{ 18, 192, 34};
    std::vector<int> vec2{ 171, 11, 50, 6};
    vec1.insert(vec1.begin()+1,vec2.begin(),vec2.end());
    vec1.erase(vec1.begin()+1);
    for (int e : vec1) std::cout << e << ' ';
}
```

Output:

```
18 11 50 6 192 34
```

I inserted the other way around, but it should be easy to adjust. Also doing the same with smart pointers does not require a different algorithm/method to be used. If you want to keep the original vector you only need to make a copy before inserting.

PS: I first misread the question and missed the part of removing the element in the place where you insert. My fixed solution is not the most efficient, because inserting and erasing the old element could be done in one go. However, for not too big vectors the difference in efficiency might be negligible.

Comment: yeah but does it work with smart pointers like unique and shared ptr?